# DHCP options "not user configurable"

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I'm using dhcp on both client and server on Linux machine 
I would like to "force" some dhcp options from the dhcp server to the dhcp client 
Specifically I'd like the client to set into his lease database the following options: `dhcp-renewal-time` and `dhcp-rebinding-time`
So far I was not able to have the client adding such options to his lease database. Reading the dhcp-options man page I noticed the following paragraph:

From: `man 5 dhcp-options`

> Some of the options documented here are automatically generated by the
>   DHCP server or by clients, and cannot be config‐
>          ured by the user.  The value of such an option can be used in the configuration file of  the  receiving  DHCP  protocol
>          agent  (server  or  client), for example in conditional expressions. However, the value of the option cannot be used in
>          the configuration file of the sending agent, because the value is determined only after the configuration file has been
>          processed. In the following documentation, such options will be shown as "not user configurable"

Both options I'm interested in are marked as "not user configurable", but my understanding of the above paragraph is that, depending on the option, only one of the side (client or server) can configure the parameter. In this specific scenario I would imagine that the server can communicate the client the values for renewal and rebinding, not the other way around. Is this correct? Someone out there succeeded in configuring such options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to dhcpd 4.2.x. Those parameters are user configurable in that version.

https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-01193/0/DHCP-4.2.7-Release-Notes.html

Answer (score 2):

I've always understood that the renewal time is 50% of the lease time and is calculated when the lease is handed out. The client will attempt to contact the original DHCP server when this times out.

The Rebinding time is 87.5% of the lease time and again is calculated when the lease is handed out. If it times out the client will attempt to contact any DHCP server to renew it's IP address.

These timers are reset whenever a new lease is obtained. There is a discussion of this in the [TCP/IP Guide](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DHCPLeaseLifeCycleOverviewAllocationReallocationRe.htm)

The only way you can affect these values is to change the lease time.

Comment: You are right, but I'm trying to reproduce a scenario with a device that is sending to my client the above options explicitly: ie in my lease db I have:   option dhcp-renewal-time 1800;  option dhcp-rebinding-time 3150;

Comment: @sergico: You can't do that because they're not user configurable.